# The most natural way of asking for telephone call redirection

Tags: conversation, telephone

What is the most natural way to ask a hotel receptionist or a secretary to transfer your call to a hotel room or an office?

> Could you please connect me with room number 321?
>
> Could you please transfer my call to room number 321?

and

> Could you please connect me with [name]'s office?
>
> Could you please transfer my call to [name]'s office?

I would like to know some more informal or maybe slang terms, specifically US ones.

Comment: "Room 321, please."

Comment: Perfect question for ELL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always use the phrasal verb *"put through to",* which is specific to phone calls. For example, *"Could you please put me through to room 321?"*

Answer (score 4):

There are certainly many ways to do this. I would suggest saying it one of two ways:

> Hello, could you please transfer me to room 321?

or the slightly more informal

> Room 321, please.

Answer (score 1):

I regard requests or statements like “Give me room 321, please” and “I'd like to speak with Jane Doe in room 321” as natural, along with previously-suggested “Room 321, please”.  But previous suggestions containing phrases like “transfer **me**” or “put **me** through” seem to me rather unnatural (even if idiomatic).  I'd prefer to hear “transfer **my call**” or “put **my call** through”.

Comment: The poster asked for informal expressions; I find "transfer" unqualified in that respect. And to my ear and mouth, "put my call through" is much more unnatural than "put me through".

Comment: @RustyTuba, I don't agree "put my call through" is unnatural, but do agree that the "my call" forms are more formal than the "me" forms.  Anyway, I don't particularly like any of the *transfer* or *put through* forms, and as stated prefer "Give me..." and "I'd like to speak..." forms.

Comment: No, "put my call through" is not unnatural; I just feel it's more unnatural that "put me through," support for which is ample through a bit of googling.